# Optimize queries with count (distinct)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

I have a SQL query a simplified version of which looks something like this:

```
SELECT
      ff.f_id AS field_id,
      COUNT(DISTINCT pca.pc_id) AS num_distinct_bundles,
      COUNT(DISTINCT pca.p_id) AS num_distinct_programs
FROM
      sometable  ff,
      sometable2 b,
      sometable3 pca
WHERE
          ff.f_id = b.f_id
      AND b.pc_id = pca.pc_id
GROUP BY
      ff.f_id;
```

The problem is the `COUNT(DISTINCT)`. It takes up a lot of time. I tinkered and found out that

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(column)
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT column from tableX) as tableY
```

is faster than using `COUNT(DISTINCT)`directly. I was able to write part of the query as

```
SELECT
    ff.f_id AS field_id,
    COUNT(t1.pc_id) as num_distinct_bundles
FROM
    sometable ff,
    sometable2 b,
    (SELECT DISTINCT pca.pc_id FROM sometable3 AS pca) AS t1
WHERE
         ff.f_id = b.f_id
    AND  b.pc_id = t1.pc_id
GROUP BY
    ff.f_id
```

This reduced my query time for the first two columns to almost 1/4 of the initial time. However I could not think of a way to get the second column that is `num_distinct_programs`

Can this be done in a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Try if this will make any difference:

```
SELECT
    ff.f_id AS field_id, t1.num_distinct_bundles, t2.num_distinct_programs
FROM
    sometable ff 
    INNER JOIN sometable2 b ON ff.f_id = b.f_id,
    (
    SELECT COUNT(t.pc_id) as num_distinct_bundles
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT pca.pc_id FROM sometable3
        ) AS t
    ) as t1,    
    (
    SELECT COUNT(t.p_id) as num_distinct_programs
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT pca.p_id FROM sometable3 
        ) AS t
    ) as t2 

GROUP BY
    ff.f_id
```

Comment: I think there is an error in the query.. In the inner join clause there would not be a table as ff.. Am I right?

Comment: yes there was a error in the join fixed it, like this it works for me (tryed same aproach on one of my tables)

Comment: What about the where clause in my query in the question `b.pc_id = pca.pc_id` ?